# How to program this action in bash?

Tags: command-line, 18.04, bash, bluetooth

I would like to create and execute .sh script via which I would be able to trigger the bluetooth connection an pair my AirDots.

The command is `bluetoothctl`
[image]

but I want to have a script where the commands will first execute `bluetoothctl`, then `connect  XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX`.

Thank you in advance.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the solution for my own question.

Maybe it would be useful for someone.

To connect to the specific device:

`echo -e 'power on\nconnect 1C:52:16:A5:86:18\t \nquit' | bluetoothctl`

But if there is a bluetooth device turned off

`sudo systemctl start bluetooth`

Overall:

`#!/bin/bash 
sudo systemctl start bluetooth
sleep 2
echo -e 'power on\nconnect [Mac-address] \t \nquit' | bluetoothctl`

Answer (score 2):

You'd do something like

```sh
#!/bin/sh

# find the MAC address of the device
macaddr=$( bluetoothctl | awk '/AirDots/ {print $3}' )

# and connect them
connect "$macaddr"
```

Save that to a file in a directory in your PATH (perhaps `$HOME/bin`) and make it executable.

It can be made more general so that "AirDots" is not hardcoded, if you have other devices you want to be able to connect.

---

Attempt #2 -- often CLI programs allow you to specify the command on the command line. It seems this is one of them.

```sh
#!/bin/sh
macaddr=$( bluetoothctl devices | awk '/AirDots/ {print $2}' )
bluetoothctl connect "$macaddr"
```

Note, my raspberry pi is in the basement with no bluetooth devices paired or available.

Comment: I tried this, but it didn't work. There is just a blank in terminal and nothing

Comment: Try running it with `bash -x name_of_script` and see what happens

Comment: `drmohm@Jacks:~$ bash -x headphone.sh
++ bluetoothctl
++ awk '/AirDots/ {print $3}'`

Comment: What about the `connect "$macaddr"` command?

Comment: you wrote `awk ' /Airdots/ {print $3} '` but the output of `bluetoothctl` command says that mac address on the third column.

Comment: Oh, wait, I see: the bluetoothctl command drops you into a CLI. Hmm

Comment: Exactly! It not just the regular command with options and arguments

Comment: Try tlat. I'm not sure what the output of `bluetoothctl devices` gives you